# What happens when bear is not able to buy back the shares (to be more precise borrowed shares) he sold?

Tags: shorting-securities

I came across the stock market jargons: Bull and Bear. A bit of research on bear helped me understand bear as the person who borrows shares/stocks with speculation that the price of the borrowed shares/stocks may fall in the future. So he/she basically borrows the shares and sells it, with an intention of buying back when the price of that stocks falls below the price at which they were sold. What happens when he/she is not able to buy back the shares, maybe because no one is willing to sell those shares.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a "market bear" is just someone who is pessimistic about "the market" (or a particular stock or set of stocks).

Comment: One can be bullish or bearish on an individual security or bullish or bearish on the market.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to a short seller, who wants to close his position, but there are no shares available for sale?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98345/what-happens-to-a-short-seller-who-wants-to-close-his-position-but-there-are-n)

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for an inability to buy a stock to cover a short position are a halt in the stock or in the market.

There have been a very small number of situations where it was almost impossible to buy to cover.  The classic example cited is Porsche's surreptitious acquisition of Volkswagen shares and derivatives prior to making surprise announcement that it had a large stake in the company. Supposedly, it made Volkswagen the [most valuable company](https://www.barrons.com/articles/tesla-2020-is-nothing-like-volkswagen-2008-yet-51580900427)
in the world at that time.

Comment: The question isn't why it can happen or when it has happened, it's what does the short seller do in that situation.

Comment: Actually it is. While it may be problematic to GO short (you must be able to find someone to borrow you the shares), there are few reasons not to be able to BUY your shares, even though you may not like the price.

Comment: Actually it does. Read the example of the Volkswagen story.  If you can't get out of your short position as share price skyrockets, what do you think happens to the value of the short seller's position and account?

Comment: If your answer is "the price goes up and the short seller loses a lot of money", that's fine, but you should just say that.  Don't say "what do you think happens" --- people ask a question because they want the answer, not to be told "what do you think happens".

Comment: The headline in the linked story clearly spells out what happens: **Tesla’s Big Gain Is Crushing Short Sellers. It’s Nothing Compared to Volkswagen in 2008**. In the body of the article it states: **Volkswagen shares rose more than 300% over the span of a couple of days in October 2008. The stock rose more than 600% from levels that prevailed before the unexpected rally gained steam**.  What part of these two statements isn't clear to you?

Comment: Then quote the headline in your article and explain in words what happens!  Otherwise it's a link-only answer.